# Arthur C Clarke story?

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find title of a story I read as a child (may be by Arthur C Clarke?) that I think my grandson will love. I only remember basic details:a family live on a planet where strange events happen - turns out planet is the toy of a giant. Hope this may spark someone else's memory

Comment: Just a couple of questions that might help us find your story- when were you a child?  Did you read the story in English?  Was it in an anthology, or a magazine, or somewhere else?  The more details, even minor ones, the better your odds.

Comment: Similar to the Twilight Zone episode [Stopover in a Quiet Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopover_in_a_Quiet_Town) written by Earl Hamner, Jr. (who created the Waltons), but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding print version.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly *Restricted Area* by Robert Sheckley.

Not a family but an exploration team on a strange planet. There is a variety of animal life (all friendly). They discover a giant metal pillar with its top hidden by clouds. The next day, the animals seem to have died and they notice that the pillar has started turning.
They deduce that the planet is a playground and the animals have wound down.

> 'The shaft is a key. The place ran down while we made our unauthorized
>   visit. Now someone's winding the planet up again.'